# Chrome URL/Search bar dark theme

Tags: google-chrome

I know there was a thing with Chrome that made the search bar dark along with your Windows theme. At first I disliked it, but I grew onto it since I use everything in dark mode it fit in. They seem to have removed the feature and I can't figure out how to get it back. So if anyone knows if it's still possible, I'd appriciate an answer.

Light mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I3YD.png

Dark mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0t5Z.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to manually change the search bar color to black, but I've installed [this theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/material-incognito-dark-t/ahifcnpnjgbadkjdhagpfjfkmlapfoel) and it changes the search bar back to dark mode.

Comment: In the description it says: "This theme has been deprecated in favour of the official Google Chrome dark theme."

Comment: but you can still use it in your browser, it just won't be updated anymore

Comment: well, I found a way to activate the official Chrome dark theme: open a new tab > at the bottom left side there's a option to customize your page > click on "color and theme" then you'll find the color options for your Google Chrome (in my case, the dark search bar only works with "Default" theme)